# Odoo 13 creating a sales record via api?

Tags: odoo

Hi I am trying to create a sales record via the odoo 13 api, I have looked at the documentation and so far I have not been able find any example, I have also asked on there forums but so far no luck. Does anyone have an example I can see?

Comment: Please provide the code you tried. Odoo documentation Clearly states how to create a record of a model. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html. 
model for sale records are "sale.order" and sale order lines are "sale.order.line"

Comment: @amal I have tried the same code from documentation, with sales records and id no luck. Do you happen to have an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following example to create a sale order using an instance of `odoo.com`

```
import xmlrpc.client

url = "https://***.odoo.com"
db = ""
username = ""
password = ""

common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))

uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})

models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

# Get partner_id and product_ids from database
# Or create them

so_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'create', [{
    'partner_id': partner_id,
    'order_line': [(0,0, {'product_id': product_id}) for product_id in product_ids]
}])
```

Comment: Lot of business logic in sales orders depends on onchange events, like setting prices, taxes and so on. I suggest to create an order without lines and call `onchange_partner_id` on the created order afterwards. Then create order lines and call `product_id_change` on every line. Maybe there are some more onchange methods to call, but those 2 are the core ones on orders.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for.